# OCMock an NSOperation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am trying to write some Unit Tests to test some custom `NSOperations` that we are writing.  What I'd like to do is create a Mock of the `NSOperation` and put it on the `NSOperationQueue`, and then wait for it to finish.  I know I can swizzle the methods and not use `OCMoc`k at all, but I really don't want to do that.  I'd like to use `OCMock`.  The code I'm trying to run is something like the following:

```
MYOperation *operation = [MYOperation new];
id mockOperation = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:operation];
[NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
[queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
[queue addOperation:mockOperation];
```

When the unit test gets to this line:

```
[queue addOperation:mockOperation];
```

I get a call to a deallocated object exception.  Anyone have any suggestions on how I can overcome this?

Comment: There is a know problem in the Apple runtime that affects OCMock when ARC is enabled. More detail here: http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=252

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ARC, `operation` is probably released right after you create the mock, as it's not accessed again. If you change it to this, it should fix the error:

```
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

...which you should be doing anyways--you're testing your object, not the mock.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if I stub out a method on the mock, does that get executed or does it execute the method on the actual Operation?

Comment: With partial mocks, if you stub/expect a method, that method will get invoked on the mock instead of the actual object. Partial mocks provide a way to intercept particular messages sent to an object. From the [OCMock docs](http://ocmock.org/#features): `When a stubbed method is invoked using a reference to anObject, rather than the mock, it will still be handled by the mock.`

Answer (score 0):

When using ARC the reference to the object in *mockOperation* will be set to nil quite aggressively (too aggressively I think) by the Apple runtime. Not all is lost, though. You can set up your stubs and expectations using *mockOperation* and still pass *operation* to the addOperation: method; the partial mock works even when you use a reference to the original object.